# How does using Tukey's test correct for multiple comparison problem?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multiple-comparisons, intuition, tukey-hsd-test

I am curious about the intuition behind the Tukey's HSD. I know that it is designed for post-hoc test(WHEN and HOW part), but I want to know underlying theory that justifies its usage(WHY part).

To phrase my question differently,  why is using the test statistic
$$q_a = \frac{Y_A - Y_B }{SE}$$

and comparing it to studentized range distribution immune to multiple comparison problem?

Comment: Do you need a *proof* of this, or do you want a conceptual explanation that will make this fact intuitive? (Some people will get the latter from the former, but typically few people do.)

Comment: @gung If possible, both :)!